# Why does my React component only render after ctrl + shift + R?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, render, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension and it only shows up after after refreshing the page with ctrl + shift + r, but now I have a problem of whenever I click on a link that ends up refreshing the page, the extension goes away and I have to hard refresh again.

I tried using window.location.reload() but sometimes it'll keep reloading the page non stop.
here's the code to render:

```
class IconExtChrome extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { _isLoggedIn: false };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
        this.popover = this.popover.bind(this);
        this.setAuthState = this.setAuthState.bind(this);
        this.setAuthState();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="bootsrtap-iso">
                <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" rootClose placement="bottom" overlay={this.popover()}>
                    <img src={chrome.runtime.getURL('favicon.png')} width="40" height="auto" />
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </div>
        )
    }


    popover(): OverlayChildren {
        return (
            <Popover className="bootstrap-iso">
                <Popover.Body className="p-2 d-grid text-center">
                    <PopoverHeader as="h4">{(this.state._isLoggedIn ? 'You are currenlty logged in' : 'You are currenlty logged out')}</PopoverHeader>
                    <Button className="m-auto mt-2" variant={this.state._isLoggedIn ? 'danger' : 'primary'} size="sm" onClick={this.state._isLoggedIn ? this.logout : this.login}>{this.state._isLoggedIn ? 'Logout' : 'Login'}</Button >
                </Popover.Body>
            </Popover>
        );
    }

    login() { Login(() => { this.setAuthState() }, () => { console.log("failed to login") }) }
    logout() { Logout(() => { this.setAuthState() }); }
    setAuthState() { IsLoggedIn((isLoggedIn: boolean) => { this.setState({ _isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn }); }); }
    refreshToken: () => { RefreshToken(); }
}

const GmailFactory = require("gmail-js");
const gmail = new GmailFactory.Gmail() as Gmail;

var btn = gmail.tools.add_toolbar_button('<div id="icon_placeholder"></div>', function () { }, 'temp_css').get(0)['className'];

const getElement = document.querySelectorAll('.' + btn.toString().replace(' ', '.'))[5]
var app: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div') as HTMLElement;
var pos: HTMLElement = getElement as HTMLElement;
if (pos !== null) {
    console.log('pos: ' + pos)
    pos.appendChild(app);
    ReactDOM.render(<IconExtChrome />, app);
}
```

Any way I could easy hard refresh the page or a proper fix for only showing up after refreshing with no cache?

Comment: We don't mark questions 'solved' here. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Noted! I thought that it'd help someone to see what's being solved or not, but I guess they can just look up the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of not rendering after a normal (F5) refresh by adding an event listener to check if the page is fully loaded. Example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const app: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div') as HTMLElement;
    const pos: HTMLElement = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/header/div[2]/div[2]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue as HTMLElement;

    pos.appendChild(app);
    ReactDOM.render(<IconExtChrome />, app);
}, false);
```